# Cakephp custom query pagination

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to use custom query in Cake then paginate the results with the code below:

```
$query = $this->Petition->query($sql);
```

I tried:

```
$petitions = $this->paginate($query);
```

and it doesn't work. Is there a way we can do this?

OK I wasn't clear enough: I need to use variable array fetched from custom query on pagination so I can use this for pagination in the view. Is there an easy way of doing this?
Below is my code:

```
function index() {
        if ($this->Session->read('Auth.User.group_id') != 1) {
            $commune_id = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.commune_id');
            $commune_id = $this->Petition->Commune->findbyId($commune_id);
            $commune_id = $this->Petition->Commune->find('all',array('conditions' => array('group' => $commune_id['Commune']['group'])));
            $count = count($commune_id);
            $i=1;
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `petitions` WHERE `commune_id` = ";
            foreach($commune_id as $commune_ids){
                if($i==1){
                $sql .= $commune_ids['Commune']['id'];
                }else{
                $sql .= " OR `commune_id` = ".$commune_ids['Commune']['id'];
                }
            /*if($i != $count){
            $this->paginate = array(
                'or' => array(
                    array('Petition.commune_id LIKE' => $commune_ids['Commune']['id'] . ","),
                    //array('Petition.commune_id LIKE' => "," . $commune_ids['Commune']['id'] . ",")
                    ),
                'limit' => 10
            );
            }*/
            $i++;
            }
            $query = $this->Petition->query($sql);
        }
        $this->Petition->recursive = 0;
        $petitions = $this->paginate();
        $this->set('petitions', $petitions);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you seriously need to read the pagination part in the cake book:

> ```
> function index() {
>     $conditions = array();
>     if ($this->Auth->user('group_id') != 1) {
>         $commune_id = $this->Petition->Commune->findById($this->Auth->user('commune_id'));
>        $conditions['Petition.id'] = $this->Petition->Commune->find('list',array(
>             'fields'=>array('id','id')
>             'conditions' => array('group' => $commune_id['Commune']['group'])
>         ));
>     }
>     $this->Petition->recursive = 0;
>     $petitions = $this->paginate('Petition',$conditions);
>     $this->set('petitions', $petitions);
> }
> ```

something like that.

Answer (score 0):

this is not how pagination works
you need to fill $this->validate with your conditions etc
and then use $this->paginate() plainly

see
http://book.cakephp.org/view/1232/Controller-Setup

also note the chapter about the custom query part if it is really(!) necessary.

Comment: did you meant `$this->paginate` instead of `$this->validate`??